# Compact split/shared Access DB

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-connection, shared

I have a split (frontend .accdb + backend .accdb) Access 365 database which is shared among some users.

I would like to periodically compact/repair it via VBA, but i wonder what would happen when it is being used by more than one user at the same time.

1. I think it is impossible to do such thing when more than one user is connected, am I wrong?
2. How can I check if more than one user is connected? A semaphore system could be weak.

Comment: If it has an active connection, you will not be able to repair/compact it. You can detect an active connection by reading the roster which will tell you the computer names of the active connections, but there is no way to "kick them out" of their connection programmatically (at least none that I have been able to find) unless you just reboot the computer that has the back end database on it. Perhaps consider migrating the back end to something more advanced, like SQL Server Express (free but has a manageable size limitation) that does not need to be repaired/compacted.

Comment: The only other thing I have to add is what I did in a similar scenario, and that was to set up a scheduled task under windows that runs Access with some special arguments (command line style) that would compact it at midnight when no one was using it. It worked fine except when people left for the day without closing the front end. So if you can make sure everyone has it closed at a specified time, that would work.

Comment: Note that you can _kick out_ clients by checking a globally available variable, e.g. a lock file, database property, or table variable, on the client every x seconds, and use that to determine if the client should disconnect. I've used a similar approach for when someone left the database open overnight, though I also recommend migrating to a different back-end, especially considering that [this bug](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-reports-that-databases-are-in-an-inconsistent-state-%EF%BB%BF-7ec975da-f7a9-4414-a306-d3a7c422dc1d) is still not fixed fully.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a small change in your front-end code that, for each user, periodically checks a back-end value signifying whether the back-end is available or usable. When I say periodically checks, it'd be best for this to be checked on every create, update or delete operation (reads are unimportant).

For example, I used to keep a tbl_Kvs (key-value store) in both the front-end and back-end for storing client and server global variables, and one of the keys in the back-end tbl_Kvs was dbReadOnly = 0 (zero representing false, the 'normal' mode of operation, allowing full CRUD access to users).

An admin can go in & set dbReadOnly = 1 (or any other non-zero value), which effectively puts the back-end into a read-only state from that point in time (providing your front-end code takes proper account of the dbReadOnly variable).

Now that your back-end file is effectively isolated from new writes, you can take a copy of it and compact/repair that copy at your own leisure, whilst the existing back-end is still serving users in a read-only fashion.

When all users have logged off, you can then switch the newly compacted copy of the back-end with the live one, and reset dbReadOnly = 0 to re-allow normal write operations.

If you don't want to wait for all users to voluntarily close their connections, you could re-code the front-end to close the application when dbReadOnly = 1 and then deny any new attempted connections (but I never really needed to use forced user booting for my scenarios).

A completely different option I used to use sometimes, was to have an event logging table in my back-end, and code in the front-end which logged all user actions (including opening & closing connections - logon & logoff). I then made an admin query which read the back-end events table, and produced a report of currently logged in users. I could then physically go round those logged in users and ask them to close the front-end for a few minutes whilst I did the compact/repair admin. This was a less strict approach I guess, better for when all the users were in the same building.